# Is textarea supported in flow variable assignment?

Tags: visual-workflow, long-text-area, textarea

I search for the restrictions using salesforce flow for field update and find nothing about texarea.

My use case is to update the related contact details field (textarea type) when the object x__c detail field (textarea type) is updated. But I saw that firstly :

1. Textarea / long text area/ rich-text field cannot be use in criteria
2. Even if a textarea is available for update, but the x__c object textarea field is not available to be used to update the contact detail field.

Is this normal ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set a textarea with a formula resource.  I concatenated a bunch of strings, but you could easily put one field in the formula.